# Frama-C: find location of loop end

Tags: c, ocaml, frama-c

In the following example code:

```
void kernel(int ni, int nj, int nk, float alpha, float *tmp, float *A, float *B) {
int i, j, k;
  for (i = 0; i < ni; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < nj; j++) {
      tmp[i * nj + j] = 0.0f;
      for (k = 0; k < nk; ++k) {
        tmp[i * nj + j] += alpha * A[i * nk + k] * B[k * nj + j];
      }
    }
}
}
```

I tried to get the location of `}` (which marks the end of each loop) without success.

- For example, for the first loop, I looked into `stmt.preds` list and found just `i = 0;` and `i++`. The `stmt.succs` list contain only the `if` test on `i < ni`.
- `}` do not corresponds to any kind of stmt or Instr and does not exist in `stmt.bstmts` list.
- Using functions in `Stmts_graph` like `get_all_stmt_last_stmts` (which give me a `break` statement and this `break` statement has the same location as the loop) don't solve the problem.

How can I get the location of my loop end (here `}`). Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Frama-C, there is no such thing as a statement which would correspond to the closing `}` in your code. Only statements that may have an observable effect (either on the memory, or on the control-flow) exist; the only exception is `Skip`, but Frama-C avoids generating those.

- if you are looking for the *line number* of the `}`, as extracted from the AST, you may look at the second component of the locations that are attached to each statement. As can be seen in `Cil_types`, locations are pairs of `Lexing.position`, and the second one represents the end of the instruction. However Frama-C makes little effort to have an accurate information for this component, as it is never displayed
- if you are looking for the AST statements that exit the loop, look for those that are inside the loop, and whose successor (`.succs` field) are outside. This particular edge will correspond more or less to your `}`. In the loop of your example, you should find the `break` statement which is created to handle the exit condition.

Comment: I searched break statements (unsing a `vstmt_aux`) either with `|Break(loc)` or by iterating on loop successors list or with `Stmts_graph.get_all_stmt_last_stmts`. But in all case, the location (obtaining with `(fst loc).Lexing.pos_lnum`) what Frama-C gives me correspond to the same location as the beginning of the loop (ie the line where the `for(i=0; ...)` statement is located) which is not the information I wish to have, I would like to be able to determine where my loop ends.

Comment: I was suggesting to use the _2nd_ component, i.e. `snd loc`, and on the location of the loop itself.

Comment: Thank, indeed the second component of the loop location itself corresponds to the location of loop end.

Answer (score -1):

to determine when loops start/stop use consistent indentation.

1. indent after every opening brace '{'
2. unindent before every closing brace '}'
3. suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Applying the above criteria to the posted code results in:

```
void kernel(int ni, int nj, int nk, float alpha, float *tmp, float *A, float *B)
{
    int i, j, k;

    for (i = 0; i < ni; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < nj; j++)
        {
            tmp[i * nj + j] = 0.0f;

            for (k = 0; k < nk; ++k)
            {
                tmp[i * nj + j] += alpha * A[i * nk + k] * B[k * nj + j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which is very easy to see where each loop starts and stops

Comment: Even though the original's code is badly indented, this does not answer the question, which is about programmatically locating statements in an AST.

Comment: AST is abstract syntax tree.